# How to record video from an old webcam using ffmpeg on Linux?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, camera, recording, video-encoding

After couple of hours I'm finally ready to accept my absolute lack of knowledge in that topic and decided to post this question here.
I've been trying to record video from an old external USB webcam (Media-Tech MT400 -> 0c45:6029) with `ffmpeg` but without much success.

First thing I've tried was to run to try something that works for the built-in webcam):

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 test.avi`

But that returned a following error:

`Cannot find a proper format for codec 'none' (id 0), pixel format 'none' (id -1)`

Here is what I get from `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1/ --all --list-formats-ext`

```
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : sonixb
        Card type     : USB camera
        Bus info      : usb-0000:04:00.0-1
        Driver version: 3.10.17
        Capabilities  : 0x85000001
                Video Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x05000001
                Video Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (sonixb: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height  : 352/288
        Pixel Format  : 'S910'
        Field         : None
        Bytes per Line: 352
        Size Image    : 126720
        Colorspace    : SRGB
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Frames per second: invalid (0/0)
        Read buffers     : 2



ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'S910'
    Name        : S910
            Size: Discrete 160x120
            Size: Discrete 176x144
            Size: Discrete 320x240
            Size: Discrete 352x288

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'BA81'
    Name        : BA81
            Size: Discrete 160x120
            Size: Discrete 176x144
```

Unfortunately that was not of much help to me, but I tried capturing webcam output with `VLC` and recording it which.... WORKED!

I tried `ffmpeg -i vlc-record[...].avi` on `VLC recording` which returned following information:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'vlc-record-2015-02-05-05h22m52s-v4l2____dev_video1-.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:01.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26937 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 352x288, 27671 kb/s, 22.10 tbr, 22.10 tbn, 22.10 tbc
```

I thought that was enough information (`rawvideo` and `yuv420p`) led to run `ffmpeg` with following arguments (I have found `yuv4` using `ffmpeg -formats`)

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec yuv4 -i /dev/video1 test.avi`

The result was only slightly better than one that I saw after my first attempt:

```
[IMGUTILS @ 0x7fff497d3920] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[rawvideo @ 0x9c4720] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: yuv4, yuv420p, -4 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
/dev/video1: could not find codec parameters
```

Again after some searching and several tries I added '-video_size cif` option and.... it WORKED!!??

Well, not really...

```
Input #0, rawvideo, from '/dev/video1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30412 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: yuv4, yuv420p, 352x288, 30412 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, avi, to 'test.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 352x288, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (yuv4 -> mpeg4)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   13 fps=6.3 q=24.8 Lsize=    1064kB time=00:00:00.52 bitrate=16759.3kbits/s    
video:1058kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.554114%
```

LED on webcam turned on as during capturing video with `VLC` but all that was recorded was TV-like noise.

So here I am after 7 hours - still without work solution - asking for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you don't mind about using other tools, Kino worked for me pretty well to capture the video.

Comment: @YoMismo thanks, I will look into that. But right now things are getting personal between me and `ffmpeg` :).